# ubuntu linux sed affects file properties?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

I have a text file of 75000 items, 2 lines for each item. line 1 has an identifier, line 2 a text string.
I need to remove 130 items, random identifiers that I have in a list or can put in a file.
I can carry out the removal for one item, but not for more than one. 
I tried piping the identifiers and get an empty output file.
I tried repeated commands of `sed -e 'expression' inputfile > outfile`. This works, but requires a new output file that then becomes the inputfile for the next iteration and so on. this might be the last resort.

I tried `sed -i in iteration`; this crashes and the error is that there is no file by the name of the inputfile. Which is clearly not the case, as I can see it, ls it and grep the number of identifiers in it. Only sed can't seem to read it.

I even found a python/biopython script online for this exact problem, it is very simple and does not give error messages, but it also removes only the first item.

I think it has something to do with file properties/temporary files that don't really exist (?). 
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 'Precise'
How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: There is zero functional difference between using `-i` and naming your own tmp file. In both cases a temp file is used, it's just that in the latter you get to name it. Ditto for whatever python script you choose to use. There is no UNIX tool that does true inline file editing - even `ed` uses an internal buffer the size of the original file and then overwrites the original when done. You're almost certainly better off just writing an awk script to do all of your changes in one pass.

Comment: Can you give a self-contained example?  I'm thinking probably a bash script that uses e.g. `seq` to generate a suitable input file, then runs your (possibly simplified) `sed` command on it?  If you then demonstrate how your results differ from expected, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty (no check if modification file is created, ...)

sed

- Assuming there is no special meta character in your pattern list

`sed 's#.*#/&/{N;d;}#' YourListToExclude > /tmp/exclude.sed
sed -f /tmp/exclude.sed YourDataFile > /tmp/YourDataFile.tmp
mv /tmp/YourDataFile.tmp YourDataFile
rm /tmp/exclude.sed`

awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ex=(ex==""?"":ex"|")$0;next}$0!~ex{print;getline;print;next}{getline}' YourListToExclude YourDataFile > /tmp/YourDataFile.tmp
mv /tmp/YourDataFile.tmp YourDataFile
```